# How to produce bar plots with column names along X axis and rows as Y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

needing some help!!

So I've been trying to plot some data, and I've found some solutions elsewhere on here but they don't seem to be working for me. An example of some data I'm working with is;

```
Sample_ID   Sample_Delivery   Organism   AMIK  AMC AMP FOV FAZ  POD
85          21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    4   4   2   2   1.4
86          21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    4   3   1   2   1.4
87          21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    5   5   3   2   1.4
88          21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    5   5   2   2   1.4
119         21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    4   4   2   2   1.4
120         21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    4   4   2   2   1.4
200         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   2   7   6   7
201         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   5.6
203         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   7
204         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   7
206         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   7
207         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   2   7   6   7
435         06/11/2018        E.FAEM       7    2   3   7   7   7
436         06/11/2018        E.FAEM     5.6    2   3   7   7   7
437         06/11/2018        E.FAEM     5.6    2   3   7   7   7
438         06/11/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   7
439         06/11/2018        E.FAEM       7    2   3   7   7   7
440         06/11/2018        E.FAEM     5.6    3   4   7   7   7
```

What I'm hoping for is to be able to plot, in a bar plot, the column headings of AMIK:POD on the x axis with the corresponding values on the Y axis and perhaps facet/filter the plots so you get a single plot for each line? For example, have 6 plots for the 6 E.coli samples from 21/08/2018?

I hope I've explained this ok and that the example data is alright as well.

Anything that will help a demoralised R user out would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` works best with a single variable containing the values to show, and multiple other variables to control the x and y axis, the color, the facet, etc. So the first step in making a ggplot is usually to reshape your data to a long format.

Then its easy to make a plot. Note that `geom_bar` creates a plot that shows the count of observations in each group, while `geom_col` shows the value of each observation.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Use dput() on your dataframe to get something easily reproducible next time
# or distill your question to something that can be worked on using one of the 
# standard datasets like cars, diamonds, iris, etc.

x <- (
"Sample_ID   Sample_Delivery   Organism   AMIK  AMC AMP FOV FAZ  POD
85          21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    4   4   2   2   1.4
86          21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    4   3   1   2   1.4
87          21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    5   5   3   2   1.4
88          21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    5   5   2   2   1.4
119         21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    4   4   2   2   1.4
120         21/08/2018        E.COL      1.4    4   4   2   2   1.4
200         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   2   7   6   7
201         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   5.6
203         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   7
204         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   7
206         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   7
207         21/08/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   2   7   6   7
435         06/11/2018        E.FAEM       7    2   3   7   7   7
436         06/11/2018        E.FAEM     5.6    2   3   7   7   7
437         06/11/2018        E.FAEM     5.6    2   3   7   7   7
438         06/11/2018        E.FAEL       7    2   3   7   6   7
439         06/11/2018        E.FAEM       7    2   3   7   7   7
440         06/11/2018        E.FAEM     5.6    3   4   7   7   7")

raw <- readr::read_table(x)

long <- raw %>% 
  pivot_longer(AMIK:POD, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

ggplot(data = long %>% filter(Sample_Delivery == "21/08/2018"), 
       aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(.~ Sample_ID)
```